# My prefix proved a girl's rank

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My prefix proved a girl's rank.
>
> My infix receives your thanks.
>
> My suffix is grey and healthy.
>
> My whole brags the wealthy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is

> PEARL

> My prefix proved a girl's rank.

> PEA is the titular device used in "The Princess and the Pea" to prove the princess' status.

> My infix receives your thanks.

> EAR is how one would receive the words "Thank you".

> My suffix is grey and healthy.

> EARL grey tea is generally considered healthy.

> My whole brags the wealthy.

> PEARL is a luxurious material often sported by the rich.

Answer (score 10):

You are:

> **STANDOFFISH**

*My prefix proved a girl's rank.*

> A female saint is usually given the honorific **[STA](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sta)** when their name is used in place names and churches (derived from the Italian, 'Santa').

*My infix receives your thanks.*

> To "**[DOFF](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doff)** one's cap" is a gesture which involves removing headgear as a sign of respect or appreciation. If somebody says 'thank you', you might bow your head or doff your cap in response.

*My suffix is grey and healthy.*

> **FISH** is a grey/silver-coloured food rich in many nutrients, usually recommended as a component of a *healthy* diet.

*My whole brags the wealthy.*

> Somebody who is **STANDOFFISH** might consider themselves as superior to others, thereby not wishing to associate too closely with people who are not of the same social standing as them (a status which is often governed by how *wealthy* one is).

Comment: +1, nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of a wild guess, and maybe only a partial answer

I think it could be:

> opulent

My prefix proved a girl's rank.

> OP could be short for Opposite which is a volleyball position (I think)

My infix receives your thanks.

> Not a clue. Pule is a word, but it means to whine or whimper.

My suffix is grey and healthy.

> Lent -> Ash Wednesday -> Grey...

My whole brags the wealthy.

> Opulent: Possessing or exhibiting great wealth.